# What are the name of these signals

Tags: calculus, signal-processing

It might be funny but there are two signals which confuse me about how to call them.

Signal1:
http://s3.postimg.org/ffefhwqyr/Capture1.png

Signal2:
http://s3.postimg.org/samf4o683/Capture2.png

I am doubtful what to call them: doublet, pulse, ....

Pulse looks like $$u(t-1)-u(t)$$ while signal2 is $$u(t-1)-2\times u(t)+u(t+1)$$

And signal 1 is integrtion of signal 2.

What are the names that address to shape of signal 1 and 2? (I mean universal names not personal convention).

Comment: [Triangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) and [Haar wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet)

Comment: @Chester Thanks for triangle. Haar is correct but misleading as I do not work with wavelets.

Comment: Well, call it Mr. Boxy-pants function if you want.

Comment: @Chester, you mean it does not have famous name without attaching to wavelets?

Comment: Not really that I know of. You could say it's a difference of indicator functions on adjacent intervals, I suppose.